# Windows 8 internet explorer 10 vhd? has anyone found one?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10, virtual-pc, vhd

I've been using microsoft virtual pc to locally run multiple internet explorer versions on my web development machine.

Most the time I pull down the vhds I need from Microsoft [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575)

however, I have not found an IE 10 vhd anywhere on microsoft.com.  I've asked microsoft [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprovirt/thread/d3fd51b5-ece1-49fb-a437-4586b65a68b3) as well.

Should I copy a windows 7 vhd and just upgrade it to IE 10 for now? cross my fingers it won't run differently on windows 8?

Comment: Which version of Windows are YOU using?

Comment: good point.  Windows XP, sadly, at the moment.  some of our IDEs and application combinations just can't handle a new OS

Comment: IE10 runs the same on Windows 7 and Windows 8. Does that answer your question? If yes, I'll make it an answer.

Comment: yeah, I've been copying my windows 7 ie 9 "standard" vhd load out with the plans to upgrade it to IE 10.  post the answer and i'll give you credit.  "touch" versus "click" would have been nice to confirm on Windows 8.

Comment: You can probably use the VMs from Modern.ie: http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running Windows XP and already have a Windows 7 VHD, I would say make a duplicate copy of it and upgrade it to IE10. IE10 for Windows 7 can be got from [here](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Info/Downloads/Default.html).

I would suggest you to upgrade to Windows 8 Pro as it includes Hyper-V and native VHD booting support. Native VHD booting is on Windows 7 as well. See [this post](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/how-to-use-a-vhd-to-dual-boot-windows-8-on-a-windows-7-pc/4847). This enables you to boot multiple Windows OSes as if running on bare metal.

Let me know if you need further clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

Yup! VM Appliances for all your base are here: http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads